# How to infer other library error in result type

Tags: rust

Im new to rust

consider this following code

```
fn my_function(text: &str) -> Result<String, _WHAT_SHOULD_I_USE_HERE_> {
        let word = OtherLib::text(&text)?;
        ...
        Ok(word)
}
```

`OtherLib::text` has a return type of Result<String, anyhow::Error>

but my problem is rust force me to add return type on my_function
I am not using anyhow on my project

is there any way to solve this, aside/without installing anyhow. And is there any easy way to auto complete this on vscode

what i expected

```
fn my_function(text: &str) -> Result<String, _JUST_INFER_IT_> {

and the caller of my function will get
Result<String, Error1 | Error2>
```

btw using _ is not working for me

```
fn my_function(text: &str) -> Result<String, _> {
// the placeholder `_` is not allowed within types on item signatures for return types
```

**Part 2**

I think rust don't have a union

so base on following the OtherLib::text, I come up with the following imaginary type

```
imaginary type: Result<String, ErrorKindEnum1 | ErrorKindEnum2 | Error>
current type  : Result<String, Error>
```

where | is union type and Error at the end is just a subset/value/kind of ErrorKindEnum3, example ErrorKindEnum3::Error1

my new problem is how I can match it like, because vscode dosent give me any intellisense

```
match value {
    ErrorKindEnum1::Error1 => todo!(),
    ErrorKindEnum1::Error2 => todo!(),
    ErrorKindEnum2::Error1 => todo!(),
    ...
    ErrorKindEnum3::Error1 => todo!(), // this is okay
    ErrorKindEnum3::Error2 => todo!(), // this should error. Not possible
}
```

as much as possible without type casting, or hardcoding type

**Part 3**

```
enum MyError {
   A, B, C
}
fn greet () -> MyError {
   if ... {
       return MyError::A;
   }

   if ... {
       return MyError::B;
   }
}


fn main() {
    match greet() {
        MyError:A => todo!(),
        MyError:B => todo!(),
        MyError:C => todo!(), // rust cant tell me this is impossible?
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think you're "not using it anyhow"? If a public function contained in *your* library returns a value of that type, then it's part of *your* contract and is very much necessary knowledge for users of your library to know about. After all, how can they deal with the error if they don't know or understand its type? If this is something you have high confidence will never happen (i.e. if it errs out then that's a bug in your code), then that's an assertion and you can `.expect` the error away. But if it's a reasonable scenario then you're responsible for the error type too.

Comment: sorry what i am new to rust and havent touch anyhow library. But what im trying to do is tell rust that this might return anyhow::Error without actually saying it. And if my function might throw multiple error, how i can tell rust to infer all that error. in typescript it can infer return type string | Error1 | Error2. I am thinking if that is possible

Comment: If you haven't already, I'd suggest reading the chapter about error handling in "the book": https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html. It should explain all the basic error handling concepts so that you know how to work with errors from libraries, use your own error types, and convert between them as necessary.

Comment: okay just another question, if the library it returning anyhow::Error, how can i match every possible error? it looks like anyhow::Error acts like a dynamic error? idk too. How can i handle it correctly. currently Im converting error to string and match it in that way. Assume that the library has multiple ErrorKind enum.

Comment: please help me, added part 2 above explaining current problem

Comment: Rust does have unions, they're called enums. Here is another guide that might help you: https://nrc.github.io/error-docs/error-design/error-type-design.html. Generally what you do in an application is have one error type that is an enum with variants for all the different errors that might occur in your program. For errors that come from other crates, you can use the `From` trait to define conversions between the external types and variants of your own enum.

Comment: ohhh i see, so i need to match all values in enum or us `_` to match all. And I am responsible to match my expected error. 

So base on my understanding rust cant help me identify that the current value im matching is not possible on current function? Am i getting it right?

please look at part 3

Comment: In your part 3, your main function needs to handle all possible variants of `MyError`, so no, Rust will not examine the body of the function that produced the error and let you skip variants it never creates. Generally what you do is create match arms for the cases you handle in specific ways, and use the `_` catch-all pattern to handle all the cases you don't need unique handling for.